# question about creating an all encompassing windows installer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I created a program in VS2008 and windows 7 32bit. To get the program to work currently a SDK needs to be installed on the machine. I am trying to create an installer for my program so that the program will run without needing the sdk. In VS2008 I created an installer with merge modules and dependencies and all. If this program runs on Windows 7 32bit, it works like I expect it to. However it will not run on say windows xp 32bit or windows vista 32bit right now.

Right now the VS2008 installer auto detects the dependencies but i believe thats just for windows 7 as XP and Vista don't work right.

I have dependency walker and have found the dependency of the programs to about 32000 different files...

I can't include them all.

Is there a way that I can make VS2008 on windows 7 32bit find the dependencies for this program to run on other windows versions as well and just put them all in together?

Sorry its a bit long but its driving me crazy.

Comment: What kind of dependencies are required? In most cases you have to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package together with your application and it should work. This package contains all required c/c++ libraries. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=a5c84275-3b97-4ab7-a40d-3802b2af5fc2&displaylang=en

Comment: they all have the C++ redistributables

Comment: but it also requires some merge modules such as Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm etc and policy_9_0_Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86.msm theres like 10 of each of those total and then some runtime .msm's for this program from the sdk. VS also then does "auto detect dependencies" and it wont include the stuff if its installed on my machine already which isnt what i want. and it wont let me add what i need to that folder.

Comment: and what i "need" im not sure of because VS wont show me and Dependency walker says its like 30,000 different files

Comment: i created a clean virtual machine for windows 7 32bit and before i did anything i ran the program installer and it works as expected. which is driving me nuts, it seems like it only auto finds dependencies for the version of windows its made on O_o

Comment: You'll have to *debug* the vista and xp installs to find out what's missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the low level files it was using depended on VS2005 and was not picked up. so it needed the Microsoft_VS80_CRT, ATL, MFC  merge modules that only come with VS2005 which they don't give you access to on microsoft. Asked somebody with VS2005 for the merge modules, they gave them to me and now it works across all platforms ive tested.